# Recursion Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded for checking if a negative number exists in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, callstack

I have a recursion methods to check if a generated random number exists in the `idNum` array. My code is below. I'm getting a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error in the recursion and not sure how I need to fix it.

```
    const idNum = terms.map((item) => {
      return parseInt(item.id);
    });

    const checkIfGeneratedIdExists = (num: number) => {
      // Number should always be < 0
      console.log(typeof num);
      if (num === 0) {
        return;
      }
      if (!idNum.includes(num)) {
        idNum.push(num);
        return num;
      } else {
        checkIfGeneratedIdExists(num);
      }
    };

    const generatedNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 20);
```

Comment: If `num` causes a recursive call, then passing the same value in will result in another recusive call. Nothing changes the value.

Comment: Also that is absolutely not how you negate a numeric value. Why are you working with strings if the values are conceptually numbers?

Comment: You also need to return the value of the recursive call: `return checkIfGeneratedIdExists(...)`

Comment: Maybe you meant `checkIfGeneratedIdExists(-num);` so you test the negated value.

Comment: You are probably checking if an array of numbers includes a string. Since [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#description) uses the [SameValueZero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) algorithm, that will always return `false`.